# svg generated by animate package is not displayed in the browser

Tags: animate, svg, dvisvgm

I am trying to generate svg file from a [multipage pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IwhVRB_HEAem1O03tYOUxac2jGt3gVlj/view?usp=sharing) using 'aniamte' package but without success!

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{animate}
   \usepackage{graphicx}    
   \begin{document}
     \animategraphics[controls]{0.75}{mymultipagepdf}{}{}
   \end{document}
```

I run `xelatex -no-pdf main.tex`

then
`dvisvgm --font-format=woff --exact --zoom=-1 --page=1 main.xdv`

I got the following svg file which is not displayed in the my browsers (firefox nor chromium):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 3.0.3 -->
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='-72.000004 -72.000009 283 297.780925'>
<g id='page1'>
<!-- animation by LaTeX-package `animate', https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate, v. 2023/06/18 -->
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj0' transform='translate(72.000004,-209.999991)'>
</g>
</defs>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj1' transform='translate(72.000004,-209.999991)'>
</g>
</defs>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj2' transform='translate(72.000004,-209.999991)'>
</g>
</defs>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj3' transform='translate(72.000004,-209.999991)'>
</g>
</defs>
<svg height='281.9993' overflow='hidden' viewBox='-72.000004 -71.999309 282.9993 281.9993' width='282.9993' x='-72.000004' y='-71.999309'>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.0'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='-72.000004' xlink:href='#_obj0' y='209.999991'/>
</g>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.1' visibility='hidden'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='-72.000004' xlink:href='#_obj1' y='209.999991'/>
</g>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.2' visibility='hidden'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='-72.000004' xlink:href='#_obj2' y='209.999991'/>
</g>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.3' visibility='hidden'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='-72.000004' xlink:href='#_obj3' y='209.999991'/>
</g>
</svg>
<defs>
<script type='text/javascript'>
<![CDATA[
var a0_idx;
var a0_on;
var a0_fr;
var a0_btnPauseLeft,a0_btnPlayLeft,a0_btnPauseRight,a0_btnPlayRight;
var a0_playsRight,a0_isPaused,a0_playing;
var a0_int;
var a0_pause,a0_playRight,a0_playLeft,a0_playBwd,a0_playFwd;
var a0_fps,a0_spd;
var a0_setFps;
var a0_seekFrame,a0_gotoNext,a0_gotoPrev;
var a0_stopFirst,a0_stopLast;
var a0_playPauseBwd,a0_playPauseFwd;
var a0_stepBwd,a0_stepFwd;
var a0_spdIncr,a0_spdDecr,a0_spdReset;
(function(){
function onload(){
if(!a0_fr){
a0_fr=new Array();
a0_on=0;
var ocg=document.getElementsByClassName('ocg');
for(var i=0;i<ocg.length;i++){
var ocgName=ocg[i].getAttribute('id').slice(1).split('.');
if(ocgName[0]==0){
a0_fr[ocgName[1]]=ocg[i];
}
}
a0_btnPauseLeft=document.getElementById('_0.PauseLeft');
a0_btnPlayLeft=document.getElementById('_0.PlayLeft');
a0_btnPauseRight=document.getElementById('_0.PauseRight');
a0_btnPlayRight=document.getElementById('_0.PlayRight');
a0_playsRight=true;
a0_isPaused=false;
a0_playing=false;
a0_fps=0.75;
a0_spd=1;
a0_setFps=function(f){
a0_fps=(f==0?1e-6:f);
if(a0_playing){
if(a0_playsRight){a0_playRight();}else{a0_playLeft();}
}
};
a0_seekFrame=function(f){
if(f>3||f<0){return -1;}
a0_idx=f;
a0_fr[a0_on].setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
a0_fr[f].setAttribute('visibility','visible');
a0_on=f;
return 0;
};
a0_stopFirst=function(){a0_pause(true);a0_seekFrame(0);};
a0_stopLast=function(){a0_pause(true);a0_seekFrame(3);};
a0_gotoNext=function(){
if(a0_seekFrame(a0_idx+1)<0){
a0_stopLast();
}
};
a0_gotoPrev=function(){
if(a0_seekFrame(a0_idx-1)<0){
a0_stopFirst();
}
};
a0_pause=function(stop){
try{clearInterval(a0_int);}catch(e){}
a0_playing=false;
a0_isPaused=!stop;
a0_btnPauseLeft.setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
a0_btnPlayLeft.setAttribute('visibility','visible');
a0_btnPauseRight.setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
a0_btnPlayRight.setAttribute('visibility','visible');
};
a0_playRight=function(){
var tmp_int;
try{tmp_int=setInterval('a0_gotoNext()',1000/a0_fps/a0_spd);}catch(e){}
try{clearInterval(a0_int);}catch(e){}
a0_int=tmp_int;
a0_playsRight=true;
a0_playing=true;
a0_isPaused=false;
a0_btnPauseLeft.setAttribute('visibility','visible');
a0_btnPlayLeft.setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
a0_btnPauseRight.setAttribute('visibility','visible');
a0_btnPlayRight.setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
};
a0_playLeft=function(){
var tmp_int;
try{tmp_int=setInterval('a0_gotoPrev()',1000/a0_fps/a0_spd);}catch(e){}
try{clearInterval(a0_int);}catch(e){}
a0_int=tmp_int;
a0_playsRight=false;
a0_playing=true;
a0_isPaused=false;
a0_btnPauseLeft.setAttribute('visibility','visible');
a0_btnPlayLeft.setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
a0_btnPauseRight.setAttribute('visibility','visible');
a0_btnPlayRight.setAttribute('visibility','hidden');
};
a0_playPauseBwd=function(){if(a0_playing){a0_pause();}else{a0_playBwd();}};
a0_playPauseFwd=function(){if(a0_playing){a0_pause();}else{a0_playFwd();}};
a0_spdIncr=function(){a0_spd*=1.1;a0_setFps(a0_fps);};
a0_spdDecr=function(){a0_spd/=1.1;a0_setFps(a0_fps);};
a0_spdReset=function(){a0_spd=1;a0_setFps(a0_fps);};
a0_stepBwd=function(){if(!a0_playing){a0_seekFrame(a0_idx-1);a0_isPaused=true;}};
a0_stepFwd=function(){if(!a0_playing){a0_seekFrame(a0_idx+1);a0_isPaused=true;}};
a0_playBwd=function(){if(a0_idx==0){a0_stopLast();}a0_playLeft();};
a0_playFwd=function(){if(a0_idx==3){a0_stopFirst();}a0_playRight();};
a0_seekFrame(0);
}
document.getElementById('anm0').addEventListener('mouseup',onMouseUpWdgt);
document.getElementById('anm0').addEventListener('mousedown',onMouseDownWdgt);
document.getElementById('anm0').addEventListener('touchend',onTouchEndWdgt);
onvisible();
}
function onvisible(){
}
function onhidden(){
if(a0_playing){a0_pause(true);}
if(!a0_isPaused)a0_playsRight=true;
if(!a0_isPaused&&a0_idx!=0)a0_seekFrame(0);
}
function onVisibilityChange(){
if(document.hidden){try{onhidden();}catch(e){}}else{try{onvisible();}catch(e){}}
}
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange',onVisibilityChange);
window.addEventListener('load',onload);
function onWidgetUpAction(event){
try{
if(event.shiftKey)a0_playsRight=!a0_playsRight;
var doplay=true;
if(a0_idx==3&&a0_playsRight){a0_stopFirst();}
if(a0_idx==0&&!a0_playsRight){a0_stopLast();}
if(doplay){if(a0_playsRight){a0_playRight();}else{a0_playLeft();}}
}catch(e){}
}
function onTouchEndWdgt(event){
event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();
if(a0_playing){try{a0_pause();}catch(e){}}else{
try{
if(event.shiftKey)a0_playsRight=!a0_playsRight;
var doplay=true;
if(a0_idx==3&&a0_playsRight){a0_stopFirst();}
if(a0_idx==0&&!a0_playsRight){a0_stopLast();}
if(doplay){if(a0_playsRight){a0_playRight();}else{a0_playLeft();}}
}catch(e){}
}
}
function onMouseDownWdgt(event){
event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();
try{if(a0_playing){a0_pause();}}catch(e){}
}
function onMouseUpWdgt(event){
event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();
onWidgetUpAction(event);
}
})();
]]>
</script>
</defs>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M-72.000004 209.999991H210.999995V-72.000004H-72.000004Z' id='anm0' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj4' transform='translate(-2.790029,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(2.790029,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(2.790029,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M11.28903 224.781244H14.78903C15.8906 224.781244 16.78903 223.88281 16.78903 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C16.78903 212.6797 15.8906 211.7812 14.78903 211.7812H11.28903H5.789C4.6875 211.7812 3.789 212.6797 3.789 213.7812V219.28124V222.78124C3.789 223.88281 4.6875 224.781244 5.789 224.781244Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M13.28903 221.08203L9.19138 218.28124L13.28903 215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M7.789 221.08203V215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='2.790029' xlink:href='#_obj4' y='225.780916'/>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M2.790029 225.780916H17.136255V211.434689H2.790029Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_stopFirst();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj5' transform='translate(-17.136255,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(17.136255,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(17.136255,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M25.63672 224.781244H29.13672C30.23828 224.781244 31.13672 223.88281 31.13672 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C31.13672 212.6797 30.23828 211.7812 29.13672 211.7812H25.63672H20.1367C19.0352 211.7812 18.1367 212.6797 18.1367 213.7812V219.28124V222.78124C18.1367 223.88281 19.0352 224.781244 20.1367 224.781244Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M26.63672 221.08203L22.53516 218.28124L26.63672 215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='17.136255' xlink:href='#_obj5' y='225.780916'/>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M17.136255 225.780916H31.482481V211.434689H17.136255Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_stepBwd();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj6' transform='translate(-31.482481,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(31.482481,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(31.482481,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M46.484377 224.781244H34.4844C33.3828 224.781244 32.4844 223.88281 32.4844 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C32.4844 212.6797 33.3828 211.7812 34.4844 211.7812H46.484377' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M44.28125 221.78124V214.7812' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='2' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linejoin='bevel'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.PauseLeft' visibility='hidden'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='31.482481' xlink:href='#_obj6' y='225.780916'/>
</g>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj7' transform='translate(-31.482481,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(31.482481,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(31.482481,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M46.484377 224.781244H34.4844C33.3828 224.781244 32.4844 223.88281 32.4844 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C32.4844 212.6797 33.3828 211.7812 34.4844 211.7812H46.484377' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M46.484377 211.7812V224.781244' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.1' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M41.48438 221.78124V214.7812L36.48438 218.28124Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.PlayLeft'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='31.482481' xlink:href='#_obj7' y='225.780916'/>
</g>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M31.482481 225.780916H45.828707V211.434689H31.482481Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_playPauseBwd();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj8' transform='translate(-45.828707,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(45.828707,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(45.828707,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M45.828124 224.781244H57.8281C58.9297 224.781244 59.8281 223.88281 59.8281 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C59.8281 212.6797 58.9297 211.7812 57.8281 211.7812H45.828124' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M48.02734 221.78124V214.7812' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='2' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linejoin='bevel'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.PauseRight' visibility='hidden'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='45.828707' xlink:href='#_obj8' y='225.780916'/>
</g>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj9' transform='translate(-45.828707,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(45.828707,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(45.828707,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M45.828124 224.781244H57.8281C58.9297 224.781244 59.8281 223.88281 59.8281 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C59.8281 212.6797 58.9297 211.7812 57.8281 211.7812H45.828124' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M45.828124 211.7812V224.781244' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.1' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M50.82812 221.78124V214.7812L55.82812 218.28124Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<g class='ocg' id='_0.PlayRight'>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='45.828707' xlink:href='#_obj9' y='225.780916'/>
</g>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M45.828707 225.780916H60.174933V211.434689H45.828707Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_playPauseFwd();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj10' transform='translate(-60.174933,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(60.174933,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(60.174933,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M66.67578 224.781244H63.17578C62.07422 224.781244 61.17578 223.88281 61.17578 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C61.17578 212.6797 62.07422 211.7812 63.17578 211.7812H66.67578H72.1758C73.2773 211.7812 74.1758 212.6797 74.1758 213.7812V219.28124V222.78124C74.1758 223.88281 73.2773 224.781244 72.1758 224.781244Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M65.67578 221.08203L69.77344 218.28124L65.67578 215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='60.174933' xlink:href='#_obj10' y='225.780916'/>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M60.174933 225.780916H74.521159V211.434689H60.174933Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_stepFwd();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj11' transform='translate(-74.521159,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(74.521159,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(74.521159,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M81.01953 224.781244H77.51953C76.41797 224.781244 75.519529 223.88281 75.519529 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C75.519529 212.6797 76.41797 211.7812 77.51953 211.7812H81.01953H86.5195C87.6211 211.7812 88.5195 212.6797 88.5195 213.7812V219.28124V222.78124C88.5195 223.88281 87.6211 224.781244 86.5195 224.781244Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M79.01953 221.08203L83.12109 218.28124L79.01953 215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M84.51953 221.08203V215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='74.521159' xlink:href='#_obj11' y='225.780916'/>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M74.521159 225.780916H88.867385V211.434689H74.521159Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_stopLast();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj12' transform='translate(-93.171283,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(93.171283,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(93.171283,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M99.67187 224.781244H96.17187C95.07031 224.781244 94.17187 223.88281 94.17187 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C94.17187 212.6797 95.07031 211.7812 96.17187 211.7812H99.67187H105.1719C106.2734 211.7812 107.1719 212.6797 107.1719 213.7812V219.28124V222.78124C107.1719 223.88281 106.2734 224.781244 105.1719 224.781244Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M97.87109 218.28124H103.4727' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linejoin='bevel'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='93.171283' xlink:href='#_obj12' y='225.780916'/>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M93.171283 225.780916H107.517509V211.434689H93.171283Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_spdDecr();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj13' transform='translate(-107.517509,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(107.517509,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(107.517509,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M114.01953 224.781244H110.51953C109.41797 224.781244 108.51953 223.88281 108.51953 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C108.51953 212.6797 109.41797 211.7812 110.51953 211.7812H114.01953H119.5195C120.6211 211.7812 121.5195 212.6797 121.5195 213.7812V219.28124V222.78124C121.5195 223.88281 120.6211 224.781244 119.5195 224.781244Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M115.01953 221.08203V215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M111.01953 220.78124L114.51953 218.28124L111.01953 215.78124Z'/>
<path d='M119.0195 220.78124L115.51953 218.28124L119.0195 215.78124Z'/>
<path d='M110.51953 218.28124H111.01953M119.5195 218.28124H119.0195' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='square'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='107.517509' xlink:href='#_obj13' y='225.780916'/>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M107.517509 225.780916H121.863735V211.434689H107.517509Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_spdReset();' opacity='0'/>
<defs>
<g class='xform' id='_obj14' transform='translate(-121.863735,-225.780916)'>
<g transform='translate(121.863735,225.780916)scale(0.95645,0.95645)scale(-1)translate(121.863735,225.780916)scale(-1)'>
<path d='M128.36328 224.781244H124.86328C123.76172 224.781244 122.863283 223.88281 122.863283 222.78124V219.28124V213.7812C122.863283 212.6797 123.76172 211.7812 124.86328 211.7812H128.36328H133.8633C134.9648 211.7812 135.8633 212.6797 135.8633 213.7812V219.28124V222.78124C135.8633 223.88281 134.9648 224.781244 133.8633 224.781244Z' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='.5' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round'/>
<path d='M126.5625 218.28124H132.1641M129.36328 221.08203V215.4805' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-linejoin='bevel'/>
</g>
</g>
</defs>
<use transform='matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)' x='121.863735' xlink:href='#_obj14' y='225.780916'/>
<path class='annot' cursor='pointer' d='M121.863735 225.780916H136.209962V211.434689H121.863735Z' onmousedown='event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();a0_spdIncr();' opacity='0'/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: As we don't know your `mymultipagepdf` it is hard to say a lot. But if I do the same with `example-image-a4-numbered` instead of `mymultipagepdf`, it does work and, e.g., firefox shows the red page number 1 with the controls.

Comment: I tested with `example-movie.pdf`, also part of pkg `mwe`, and the SVG output made with OP's workflow looks and runs as normal in Chromium. Using TeXLive 2023 (dvisvgm 3.0.3) and Ghostscript 10.02.0 on Linux.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, make your PDF available for download somewhere?

Comment: @AlexG [mymultipagepdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IwhVRB_HEAem1O03tYOUxac2jGt3gVlj/view?usp=sharing) generated with asymptote

Comment: @cabohah I have updated the post with a link to the pdf file I have used!

Comment: Your example works out without a problem: https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/texsx-701171.svg  (2 times xelatex + dvisvgm-3.0.3, Ghostscript 10.02).

Comment: @AlexG I don't undestand where is the problem!!!

Comment: I compared your svg output with mine. The svg code of all four animation frames is missing. I suspect a missing `mutool` installation on your system. The `mutool` command is part of the MuPDF software package (open-source, also from Artifex which produce Ghostscript). It is needed by `dvisvgm` to convert PDF into SVG code. Get it here: https://mupdf.com/releases/

Comment: @AlexG `mutool version 1.23.4`

Comment: Looks good. I have only mutool-1.22.0 which worked out as well. But if you are on linux, use the system's package manager to install MuPDF.

Answer (score 1):

`dvisvgm` relies on external software to convert PDF to SVG code. Formerly, it used Ghostscript. But recently, Ghostscript got a new PDF interpreter that is no more compatible with the needs of `dvisvgm`. Therefore, M. Gieseking, the developer of `dvisvgm`, had to resort to an alternative PDF interpreter, which is `mutool`. It is part of the MuPDF software package and is open-source. It is available as precompiled binary pkgs for Windows and other platforms, but also as source code. On Linux, use the system's package manager to install MuPDF. The upstream download site is: https://mupdf.com/releases/

The `dvisvgm` manual says that `mutool` is automatically chosen as PDF interpreter if it is found in the search `PATH` for binaries: https://dvisvgm.de/Manpage/dvisvgm.pdf#page=9

Also, acc. to the manual, the use of `mutool` can be enforced via the environment variable `DVISVGM_PDF_PROC`. Invoke `dvisvgm` as

```
DVISVGM_PDF_PROC=mutool dvisvgm ...
```

on the command line.

Comment: mutool 1.23 was already installed on my system. Since you have mutool 1.22 I will downgrade and try again! May be ???

Comment: Don't think that downgrading MuPDF is needed. It is rather a settings issue of dvisvgm.

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: Are you on Linux? Can `mutool` be invoked on the command line? See the link to the dvisvgm manual at the end of my answer.

Comment: I am on linux and I can run mutool on the command line

Comment: Is `mutool` missing in the output of `dvisvgm -V1`? Do you get a warning message when trying to convert a PDF file with `dvisvgm -P myfile.pdf`? If yes, you're probably affected by a bug in dvisvgm 3.0.3 which was fixed in version 3.0.4. I suggest to update to the latest version 3.1.2 if possible.

Comment: @Martin `dvisvgm -V1
dvisvgm 3.0.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
-----------------------------------
brotli:      1.0.9
clipper:     6.2.1
freetype:    2.13.0
Ghostscript: 10.2.0
kpathsea:    6.3.5
mutool:      1.23.4
potrace:     1.16
xxhash:      0.8.1
zlib:        1.2.13`

Comment: @ I know that dvisvgm rely on mutool to convert pdf files but is this also true for dvi  xdv files ???

Comment: If the DVI/XDV file references an external PDF file as in your example, then dvisvgm needs `mutool` to process it. What happens if you try to convert a PDF file with dvisvgm (using option `-P`)? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @Martin I get the output : The old, written in PostScript, PDF interpreter has been removed entirely.
You should cease using -dNEWDPF as it has no effect nprocessing PDF file
  graphic size: 0pt x 0pt (0mm x 0mm)
  output written to force_moment-1.svg
1 of 4 pages converted in 0.159242 seconds

Comment: I built mupdf -1.23.4, now having the same environment: `dvisvgm 3.0.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) ----------------------------------- brotli: 1.0.9 clipper: 6.2.1 freetype: 2.13.0 Ghostscript: 10.2.0 kpathsea: 6.3.5 mutool: 1.23.4 potrace: 1.16 xxhash: 0.8.1 zlib: 1.2.13`. The OP example perfectly compiles and the SVG output runs in Firefox and Chromium afterwards.

Comment: I guess, [this bug](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues/232) prevents a proper conversion. It appears only sporadically and not on all machines. @HafidBoukhoulda in this case you need to update dvisvgm. The message about the old PDF interpreter is generated by Ghostscript. When dvisvgm 3.0.3 was released, option `-dNEWPDF` was still available.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda As Alex already mentioned, please execute `export DVISVGM_PDF_PROC=mutool` and try the conversion again.

Comment: @Martin same result after `export ...`

Comment: Sorry, then I fear you need to update dvisvgm.

Comment: @Martin updating dvisvgm fixed the issue thanks!