# How to update dvisvgm to the last release not yet availble in texlive 2023

Tags: packages, texlive, dvisvgm

In [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/701171/91130) about creating svg file with the `animate` package it is sugested that I upgrade dvisvgm to version 3.1 which is available on ctan but not in texlive 2023. Unfortunately I don't know How to do this! If that help I am using linux manjaro.

Comment: Nowadays, most programs are on github and this is where I usually start searching.

Comment: @Celdor I have found the program on [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/dvisvgm/) but I don't know how to upgrade in texlive!

Comment: You'll need to wait for TL'24 as it's a binary

Comment: there are precompiled binaries at https://dvisvgm.de/Downloads/

Comment: The CTAN page contains a [README](https://mirrors.ctan.org/dviware/dvisvgm/README) with instructions on how to build the binary. The last step is `sudo make install`, which should replace the old binary system-wide by the new one, i.e., perform the actual upgrade.

Comment: @Marijn building dvsigm from source is not really trivial - it has a lot of tricky dependencies...

Comment: @samcarter I didn't say it was trivial :) I just commented on the "I don't know how to do this" part of the question.

Comment: `dvisvgm` would need to be compiled in a TeXLive build environment (`git clone https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source.git`). In a new branch (e. g. `git checkout -b updatedvisvgm`), `dvisvgm` source files would need to be replaced with the upstream ones from https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm. Configure and build instructions are contained in file  https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/dvisvgm/TLpatches/TL-Changes.

Comment: @AlexG I have installed the dvisvgm 3.1 package from manjaro but when I run it I get a kapathsea warning : configuration file not found texmf.cnf not found

Comment: This is why it should be built in a TeXLive environment and the produced binary be copied over into the existing TeXLive installation. I will try tomorrow on my own.

Comment: @AlexG I have installed texlive-bin from manjaro repos. I have created a link  dvisvgm31 to /usr/bin/dvisvgm to avoid conflict with the texlive dvisvgm binary. Then I have used dvisvgm31 to create the svg file. That works!!! Thanks to all of you!